# Angular ESLint : Any Data Type Warning

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, eslint, angular10

I am using Angular 10. We have lot of developers using `: any` date type when they shouldn't be. Is there a way to flag a warning in ESLint/TSLint, if a person utilizes this datatype ?

How can this be done in ESLint settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TS Lint has the [`no-any` rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-any/) that you can use.

> ```
> "rules": { "no-any": true }
> ```

Comment: great!, also, what is the eslint equivalent?